# Why is my react table not rendering data for the field EmployeeID?

Tags: reactjs

So my react table is rendering data for the EmployeeName, Department, DOJ and Options but nothing for EmployeeID. In MySQL I noticed the field Employee id was spelled with a capital ID. In my code I had it as lowercase. I went through and changed every EmployeeId to EmployeeID and still nothing renders for this field. Below is my code for Employee.js. Any help will be appreciated.

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {variables} from './Variables.js';

export class Employee extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state={
            departments:[],
            employees:[],
            modalTitle:"",
            EmployeeID:0,
            EmployeeName:"",
            Department:"",
            DateOfJoining:"",
            PhotoFileName:"anonymous.png",
            PhotoPath:variables.PHOTO_URL
        }
    }

    refreshList(){

        fetch(variables.API_URL+'employee')
        .then(response=>response.json())
        .then(data=>{
            this.setState({employees:data});
        });
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.refreshList();
    }

    changeEmployeeName =(e)=>{
        this.setState({EmployeeName:e.target.value});
    }
    changeDepartment =(e)=>{
        this.setState({Department:e.target.value});
    }
    changeDateofJoining =(e)=>{
        this.setState({DateOfJoining:e.target.value});
    }

    addClick(){
        this.setState({
            modalTitle:"Add Employee",
            EmployeeID:0,
            EmployeeName:"",
            Department:"",
            DateOfJoining:"",
            PhotoFileName:"anonymous.png"
        });
    }
    editClick(emp){
        this.setState({
            modalTitle:"Edit Employee",
            EmployeeID:emp.EmployeeId,
            EmployeeName:emp.EmployeeName,
            Department:emp.Department,
            DateOfJoining:emp.DateOfJoining,
            PhotoFileName:emp.PhotoFileName
        });
    }

    createClick(){
        fetch(variables.API_URL+'employee',{
            method:'POST',
            headers:{
                'Accept':'application/json',
                'Content-Type':'application/json'
            },
            body:JSON.stringify({               
               EmployeeName:this.state.EmployeeName,
               Department:this.state.Department,
               DateOfJoining:this.state.DateOfJoining,
               PhotoFileName:this.state.PhotoFileName 
            })    
        })
        .then(res=>res.json())
        .then((result)=>{
            alert(result);
            this.refreshList();
        },(error)=>{
            alert('Failed');
        }) 
    }


    updateClick(){
        fetch(variables.API_URL+'employee',{
            method:'PUT',
            headers:{
                'Accept':'application/json',
                'Content-Type':'application/json'
            },
            body:JSON.stringify({
               EmployeeID:this.state.EmployeeId,
               EmployeeName:this.state.EmployeeName,
               Department:this.state.Department,
               DateOfJoining:this.state.DateOfJoining,
               PhotoFileName:this.state.PhotoFileName 
            })    
        })
        .then(res=>res.json())
        .then((result)=>{
            alert(result);
            this.refreshList();
        },(error)=>{
            alert('Failed');
        }) 
    }

    
    deleteClick(id){
        if(window.confirm('Are you sure?')){
        fetch(variables.API_URL+'employee/'+id,{
            method:'DELETE',
            headers:{
                'Accept':'application/json',
                'Content-Type':'application/json'
            }
        })
        .then(res=>res.json())
        .then((result)=>{
            alert(result);
            this.refreshList();
        },(error)=>{
            alert('Failed');
        }) 
    }
}
    imageUpload=(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();

        const formData=new FormData();
        formData.append("file",e.target.files[0],e.target.files[0].name);

        fetch(variables.API_URL+'employee/savefile',{
            method:'POST',
            body:formData
        })
        .then(res=>res.json())
        .then(data=>{
            this.setState({photoFileName:data});
        })
    }
    render(){
        const {
            departments,
            employees,
            modalTitle,
            EmployeeID,
            EmployeeName,
            Department,
            DateOfJoining, 
            PhotoPath,
            PhotoFileName
        }=this.state;

        return(
<div>

    <button type="button"
    className="btn btn-primary m-2 float end"
    data-bs-toggle="modal"
    data-bs-target="#exampleModal"
    onClick={()=>this.addClick()}>
        Add Employee
    </button>
    <table className="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
       <th>
           EmployeeID
       </th>       
       <th>
           EmployeeName 
       </th>
       <th>
           Department
       </th>
       <th>
           DOJ
       </th>
       <th>
           Options
       </th>
   </tr>
   </thead>   
   <tbody>
        {employees.map(emp=>
           <tr key={emp.EmployeeID}>
               <td>{emp.EmployeeId}</td>
               <td>{emp.EmployeeName}</td>
               <td>{emp.Department}</td>
               <td>{emp.DateOfJoining}</td>
               <td>
               <button type="button"
               className="btn btn-light mr-1"
               data-bs-toggle="modal"
               data-bs-target="#exampleModal"
               onClick={()=>this.editClick(emp)}>  
                   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" className="bi bi-pencil-square" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                   <path d="M15.502 1.94a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .706L14.459 3.69l-2-2L13.502.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .707 0l1.293 1.293zm-1.75 2.456-2-2L4.939 9.21a.5.5 0 0 0-.121.196l-.805 2.414a.25.25 0 0 0 .316.316l2.414-.805a.5.5 0 0 0 .196-.12l6.813-6.814z"/>
                   <path fillRule="evenodd" d="M1 13.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 2.5 15h11a1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5-1.5v-6a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v6a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-11a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5v-11a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5H9a.5.5 0 0 0 0-1H2.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1 2.5v11z"/>
                   </svg>              
               </button>    
              
               <button type="button"
               className="btn btn-light mr-1"
               onClick={()=>this.deleteClick(emp.EmployeeId)}>   
                   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" className="bi bi-trash-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                   <path d="M2.5 1a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v1a1 1 0 0 0 1 1H3v9a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h6a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V4h.5a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V2a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H10a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H7a1 1 0 0 0-1 1H2.5zm3 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v7a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-7a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zM8 5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v7a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-7A.5.5 0 0 1 8 5zm3 .5v7a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-7a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0z"/>
                   </svg>      
               </button>

            </td>
        </tr>        
        )}  
   </tbody>
   </table>

<div className="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabIndex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
<div className="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered">
<div className="modal-content">
    <div className="modal-healer">
        <h5 className="modal-title">{modalTitle}</h5>
        <button type="button" className="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"
        ></button>
    </div>

<div className="modal-body">
  <div className="d-flex flex-row bd-highlight mb-3"></div>

   <div className="p-2 w-50 bd-highlight"></div>        

    <div className="input-group mb-3">
        <span className="input-group-text">Emp Name</span>
        <input type="text" className="form-control"
        value={EmployeeName}
        onChange={this.changeEmployeeName}/>
    </div>

    <div className="input-group mb-3">
        <span className="input-group-text">Department</span>
        <select className="form-select"
        onChange={this.changeDepartment}
        value={Department}>
            {departments.map(dep=><option key={dep.DepartmentId}>
                {dep.DepartmentName}
            </option>)}
        </select>
    </div>

    <div className="input-group mb-3">
        <span className="input-group-text">DOJ</span>
        <input type="date" className="form-control"
        value={DateOfJoining}
        onChange={this.changeDateofJoining}/>                
    </div>

 
 <div className="p-2 w-50 bd-highlight">
     <img width="250px" height="250px"
     src={PhotoPath+PhotoFileName}/>
     <input className="m-2" type="file" onChange={this.imageUpload}/>
 </div>      
 </div>

 {EmployeeID==0?
        <button type="button"
        className="btn btn-primary float-start"
        onClick={()=>this.createClick()}
        >Create</button>
        :null}

      {EmployeeID!==0?
        <button type="button"
        className="btn btn-primary float-start"
        onClick={()=>this.updateClick()}
        >Update</button>
        :null}
     </div>
    </div>       

              



    
      
        

       
    
</div>
</div>






        )
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your data actually look like? Did you console.log the `employees` array?

Comment: You're using two different casings within your JSX, this seems highly likely to be a typo problem and only you have the answer to what the correct casing is.

Comment: @Brian Thompson and Zargold thanks for your help. Once I went through and made the changes to EmployeeID the data rendered. I greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

In your question you say that you changed all instances of `EmployeeId` to `EmployeeID` yet I see 3 instances of `EmployeeId` still there.

While we're on the topic I would say it would help legibility and improve your ability to catch errors if you used conventional spacing like:

```
{
EmployeeID: 0
// instead of EmployeeId:0
}
```

```js
 editClick(emp){
        this.setState({
            modalTitle:"Edit Employee",
            EmployeeID:emp.EmployeeId, // here
            EmployeeName:emp.EmployeeName,
```

Here:

```js
updateClick(){
        fetch(variables.API_URL+'employee',{
            method:'PUT',
            headers:{
                'Accept':'application/json',
                'Content-Type':'application/json'
            },
            body:JSON.stringify({
               EmployeeID:this.state.EmployeeId, // here
               EmployeeName:this.state.EmployeeName,
               Department:this.state.Department,
               DateOfJoining:this.state.DateOfJoining,
               PhotoFileName:this.state.PhotoFileName 
            })    
        })
```

```js
 onClick={()=>this.deleteClick(emp.EmployeeId)}>
```